# Soft Question: Do most mathematicians agree that the function is "the most important concept in all of mathematics"?

Tags: functions, soft-question, education

Spivak (Calculus, 3e, p. 39) writes:

> Undoubtedly the most important concept in all of mathematics is that
>   of a function---in almost every branch of modern mathematics functions turn out to be the central objects of investigation.

My question is: Would most mathematicians agree with this claim? (I'd like to be able to confidently quote this to high-school students learning about functions and calculus.)

Comment: I'd certainly agree with that statement, for example because functions between objects of interest allow us to transfer results about one of these objects to the other. But then if another author says that the concept of set or the concept of infinity or the concept of category is most important, I'd wholeheartedly agree as well.

Comment: I am taking mathematical analysis at the moment (using that exact book), and every single tutor I've been through has made this claim. However, they are all 'analysts', so there might be other concepts that are equally important in other areas. 

But I definitely do not think it would be wrong to emphasis this to high school students for dramatic effect.

Comment: You will always find someone that disagrees, after all, it is a claim about _the_ most important concept in _all_ of mathematics. Nevertheless, you can always safely say that "Spivak claims that...". Also, you could use politician's version "many (prominent) mathematicians believe that..." which is technically true, and makes an illusion of the statement you actually would like to make, i.e., something like "majority of (prominent) mathematicians believe that...". Of course, only the latter is useful, but it requires some research, while the former is easy, but doesn't really say anything.

Comment: I think that the notion that there is a single most important concept in mathematics is quite implausible, if not downright ridiculous. The concept of a function is certainly *a* very important one, but any stronger assertion is sheer opinion.

Comment: I'd say it's indispensable. But saying it - or any other concept - is the morst important concept in mathematics is getting a bit silly, a sort of People Magazine type of judgement. You could tell your students one well known author in mathematics has called it the most important.

Comment: You may want to consider dropping this in the History of Science and Math SE for some more responses.

Answer (score 0):

Historically speaking, things really took off in analysis in the 17th century when the concept of *change* received a mathematical form with the development of infinitesimal calculus by the likes of Fermat, Barrow, Leibniz, and Newton. So possibly the concept of change is even more important historically than that of *function* which did not take center stage until the middle of the 18th century, and in its modern form until the middle of the 19th century.

Answer (score 0):

I remember that I was awe-struck the first time I saw the geometric definition of an ellipse turned into the equation $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ after making a few "trivial" restrictions. In all of the years that I have spent teaching and tutoring, no one else has ever expressed to me that same elation. I think that you can demonstrate a concept, but not the importance of a concept. That is a function of time, experience, and hand-built paradigms.

Answer (score 0):

A function has a precise meaning when working in a given mathematical framework.

But if you are working in [Category Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory), you might prefer to never (directly) use the word *function*, highlighting instead the concepts of arrows and morphisms.

So, why go out on a limb and say that any concept in mathematics is the 'most important'?

If anything mathematics has evolved into a process that obtains results. Defining a function as part of that process is just a result of taking the journey. The thing that has become quite evident now is that this process is all about [abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(mathematics)).

Many centuries passed without a precise definition of a function, and yet they were 'understood' in the minds of scientists and engineers and great advances were made in understanding physics and chemistry.

Today cosmologists use math to study black holes and the decade that is now passing into the history books is being recognized as the ‘golden’ decade for the study of these, um, concrete objects; see the PBS article

[3 major moments from the ‘golden’ decade of black holes](https://www.pbs.org/newshour/science/3-major-moments-from-the-golden-decade-of-black-holes)
Science Dec 27, 2019 4:33 PM EST

One can only ponder the momentous changes to mathematics as it 'assimilates' these discoveries and finds an abstract way of unifying the quantum mechanics/gravity realities of the universe.